# Bootstrap rotate whole Layout and make just on an scrolling breakpoint

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, animation, layout

i want to realise a Webpage in Bootstrap 4 or 5 like as below and need tu initial rotate the whole layout. Afer scrolling down i want to straight display (rotate so its better readable) the layout with animations.

Any idea how this can be implemented?

[image]

Comment: Use CSS `selectorHere{ transform:rotate(-45deg); }`.

Comment: I don't think bootstrap is useful for this.